# Set css styling of another class

Tags: javascript, css

I have a CSS class `.custom-service-table`, with the following style:

```
.custom-service-table{
   background: transparent;
}
```

This CSS actually set the background of a table to transparent.
For each row of the table, depending on a value, I need to update the table background.

For example, I have a bool `isActive`, if `isActive` is `true` then I need to update the table background to white.

Once I am doing the check, I am adding a CSS class to the row, `active-row`.

How can I apply a style to the class, `active-row`, so as to set the table background to white in CSS?

Comment: A `class` on the  `tr` element has no way to affect styling of any parent elements. ***Any*** selector will always only affect the targeted element, and by means of CSS inheritance, child elements.

Comment: During your loop for the TR, if bool is true, add class, if not, don't add class. We could help you better if you include your html and the loop.

Comment: how and where do you add `isActive` and `active-row` to the code?

Comment: @RamondeVries: If the bool isActive is true then add the class active-row.

Comment: @JerdineSabio:  This is already done.  What I want is that when the class active-row is present then the css should be such that the background is white.

Comment: @connexo : so there is no way of doing what I want..?

Comment: well you cannot check for an child element having a class and then style the parent if its either true or false, or you should use javascript

Comment: @refresh I see. You could set that via javascript on page ready. Are the contents added dynamically (after page load, via script)?

Comment: @JerdineSabio : On page load,  But it is a dynamic grid